# Moment js get wrong time when add days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I using moment JS

**my time now is 12/01/2020 17:30**

1. when I console log : `moment().format("LLL");` I get the right hour and date **1 December 2020 17:30**
2. when I console log :  `moment().add(0, "days");` I get wrong hour "2020-12-06T**15:30**:52.046Z"

why is it ? and how can I declare globally to set the right time of my country
(im in jerusalem its +02:00 gmt)

my global config is :

```
moment.updateLocale("he", {
weekdays: ["ראשון", "שני", "שלישי", "רביעי", "חמישי", "שישי", "שבת"],
longDateFormat: {
    LT: "HH:mm",
    LTS: "HH:mm:ss",
    L: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    LL: "D MMMM YYYY",
    LLL: "D MMMM YYYY HH:mm",
    LLLL: "dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm",
},
});
```

Comment: What's the time from the computer? I made your commands exactly as you posted and got `moment().format('LLL') //'December 1, 2020 10:35 AM'`and `moment().add(0, 'days'); //Moment<2020-12-01T10:35:50-05:00>` Same time for both commands.

Comment: On computer also 17:30...

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine but in the first example you use `format` to display a formatted time but in second you are not using format.

Try it like so: `moment().add(0, "days").format("LLL");` and it will work.

`2020-12-06T15:30:52.046Z` Is a time and date format that date is using to calculate local time for specific time zone.

Comment: and what if i want to show in this format:2020-12-06T15:30:52.046Z
but get the right hour? (17:30)